# Multiple integral equality

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

let $f:[a,b] \times [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$. If f is integrable prove that:

> $$\int_a^b \int_a^y f(x,y)dxdy = \int_a^b \int_x^b f(x,y)dydx$$

I tried derivative $\displaystyle \int_a^y f(x,y)dx$ with the Leibniz Rule and then integrate from $a$ to $b$.

I did the same with the right side of the equality but I can't get nothing.

Comment: Hint: Approximate twice by Riemann sums, and interchange the sums by using standard properties, and take limits.

Comment: It is easier if you can use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to get non-variable integration limits.

We have

$$\int_a^b \int_a^y f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_a^b \int_a^b f(x,y) \chi_{\{x \leqslant y\}}\,dx\,dy, $$

where the indicator function is defined as

$$ \chi_{\{x \leqslant y\}} = \begin{cases}1, & x \leqslant y \\0, & x > y \end{cases}$$

Now you are allowed to interchange integrals when $f$ is absolutely integrable as per Fubini's theorem or when $f$ is non-negative as per Tonelli's theorem and

$$\int_a^b \int_a^y f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_a^b\int_a^b f(x,y) \chi_{\{x \leqslant y\}}\,dy\,dx = \int_a^b \int_x^b f(x,y)\,dy\,dx $$