# Let $f$ be integrable in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Show $\int_0^1dx\int_0^xf(x,y)dy = \int_0^1dy\int_y^1f(x,y)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I can't see any clue from the problem

I have tried to prove by $"\ge" and "\le"$

The Fubini's theorem seems not help too. I stuck on this for three hours

Please at least give me some Hint if we will.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1711221/148510

Comment: I have found that too. But I have no idea how to apply it. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$
1_{[0,x]}(y)=\begin{cases}1,&\ 0\leq y\leq x\\ 0,&\ y>x\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
1_{[y,1]}(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\ y\leq x\leq1\\ 0,&\ y>x\end{cases}
$$
So, when $x,y\in[0,1]$ they are equal. Then, using that $f$ is integrable (so Fubini applies)
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\,dx&=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\,1_{[0,x]}(y)\,dy\,dx
=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\,1_{[y,1]}(x)\,dx\,dy\\ \ \\
&=\int_0^1\int_y^1f(x,y)\,dx\,dy.
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is very detail, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is Fubini's theorem on the half-square

$$
\{\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \;\;\text{and}\;\;0 \le y \le x \;\}\;=\;\{\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \le y \le 1 \;\;\text{and}\;\;y \le x \le 1 \;\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In both integrals the domain of integration (view as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$) must be the same.

From the integral at the left-hand side you first fix $x$ and let $y$ vary between $0$ and $x$ and then integrate over $x$ between $0$ and $1$.

If you draw a picture, you are integrating over the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$.

If you look at the same triangle and fix $y$ first, then you have to let $x$ vary between $y$ and $1$ and then you can integrate $y$ between $0$ and $1$. This is the integral at the right-hand side.